# Plotting intersection of multiple sets :MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, statistics

I would like to plot/visualize the intersections of multiple sets in matlab.

I found something like  [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/what-is-this-type-of-circular-link-visualization-called/3159#3159/):
[image]

Is there any way to do this in Matlab or some other way to visualize the intersection of multiple set?

Comment: is there any particular reason why you do not "accept" any answer to any of your questions?

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple of options to start from. You can use [Oleg Komarov's Schemaball](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42279-schemaball) tool from the FEX, or [Gunther Struyf's code](https://github.com/GuntherStruyf/matlab-tools/blob/master/schemaball.m) available on github

[image: Oleg Komarov's Schemaball]
This is taken using Oleg Komarov's Schemaball code...

Comment: Thanks for that. However, these seem plotting the correlation.

I was wondering if there was something on the lines of plotting the intersection of multiple(different sized) sets!

Comment: just use the machinery of the codes and make it work for you, at the end of the day you want curved lines to go from point a to point b on  a circle.